# Html.DropDownListFor selected value not being selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

EDIT: I've found a solution and what I think is the reason why, see answer below.

I've got a drop down list where the selected calue is not being rendered correctly.

The code to create is as follows:

In the controller

```
        var dlvm = new DonorIndexViewModel();

        return View(dlvm);
```

The ViewModel is created by

```
    public DonorIndexViewModel() {
        var list = CreateSearchList();
        SearchList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", list.First().Value);
    }
```

CreateSearchList is:

```
        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateSearchList() {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem> {
            CreateSelectListItem(Constants.SurnameName, Constants.SurnameValue),
            CreateSelectListItem(Constants.CodeName, Constants.CodeValue),
            CreateSelectListItem(Constants.PostcodeName, Constants.PostcodeValue),
            CreateSelectListItem(Constants.Address1Name, Constants.Address1Value)
        };


        return list;
    }
```

View code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchList, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-1"})
    <div class="col-md-11">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchListId, Model.SearchList, "Select Search Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label input-width-xlarge"})
    </div>
</div>
```

In the view, the model shows the first item is selected:
[image]

But the item is not being selected in the browser. Rendered code is as follows:

```
<select class="control-label input-width-xlarge" data-val="true" data-val-      number="The field SearchListId must be a number." data-val-required="The SearchListId field is required." id="SearchListId" name="SearchListId">
<option value="">Select Search Type</option>
<option value="1">Surname</option>
<option value="2">Code</option>
<option value="3">PostCode</option>
<option value="4">Address (Line 1)</option>
</select>
```

Everything else works fine, e.g. selected value on postback is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a property in your View Model to bind the selected value. For example `public string SelectedSearchType`. And using the helper: `Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSearchType, Model.YourSelectList)`

Comment: Can you show view code?

Comment: Added the view code, missed it out, oops :)

Answer (score 0):

The API takes in an `object` of the selected item, try:

```
SearchList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", list.First());
```

No need to add `Value`.

Comment: Didn't work, rendered html is the same, Surname does not show as selected in the view when using QuickView.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by setting the Id in the controller:

```
var dlvm = new DonorIndexViewModel();
dlvm.SearchListId = 1;

return View(dlvm);
```

The value of this seems to determine what is selected, so if it's not set - i.e. has a value 0 - then nothing is selected. Seems a bit counter-intuitive, maybe I'll put in a feature request for this!

Comment: Its not counter intuitive at all. Your binding to the property of your model so if the properties match one of the options then that option will be selected, otherwise the first option will be selected (because something has to be selected). That's how model binding works (and if it didn't, MVC would be useless!). Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored (thankfully) unless you are not binding to a model property, for example if you use `@Html.DropDownList("NotAProperty", Model.Searchist)`